# Central Difference method

Tags: matlab, math

I wrote a code to solve an ODE in MATLAB using Central Difference Method.
The Script file is

```
clc;
clear;
close all;
% Step size and paramteres
h = 0.0001;
tspan = 0:h:10;
initial_condition = 3;

% ode45 solver
[t,y] = ode45(@central_diff_f1,tspan,initial_condition);
plot(t,y);

% using the central difference
[t1,y1] = central_diff_f2(tspan,initial_condition,h);
hold on
plot(t1,y1)
legend('ODE 45','Central-Difference');
```

Here, I am trying to **OVERLAP** the solutions my function file is as follows,

```
function [t1,y1] = central_diff_f2(tspan,initial_condition,h)

y1 = zeros(size(tspan));
y1(1) = initial_condition;
t1 = tspan;
% implementing central difference approximation
for i=2:1:length(tspan)
    y1(i) = y1(i-1) + h*(3*y1(i-1)-6);
end
```

Now my **Question is**,

we know that using central difference mathematically,

[image]

if we re-arrange we get
y(t+h) ≈ y(t-h)+2h⋅y′(t)
we substitute the equation y' = 3y - 6, we get
y(t+h) ≈ y(t-h)+2h⋅(3y-6)
and now compare this which is written in code,
`y1(i) = y1(i-1) + h*(3*y1(i-1)-6);`

Why did we take t-h as i-1 and **why is coefficient of h taken 1**? (coefficient of h must be 2)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the difference in the code is a backwards difference rather than a central difference. The points it uses are (i) and (i-1), whereas for your formula you have (i+1) and (i-1). The points (i+1) and (i-1) are two points away instead of one for (i) and (i-1), which is where I think the difference in the coefficient comes from.

Answer (score 1):

I think the mixing of mathematical notation and MATLAB notation has introduced errors...

You have the correct rearrangement of the central difference:

```
y(t+h) ≈ y(t-h)+2h⋅y′(t)
```

You are using the variable `i` to loop through increments of time in steps of size `h`. Each loop you are incrementing `t = t(i)`, and the corresponding value of `y(t) = y(t(i))`. The notation becomes mixed because in your MATLAB code this just becomes `y(i)`, with `y(t+h) = y(i+1)` to denote the next timestep, and `y(t-h) = y(i-1)` to denote the previous timestep.

In short, the value at the ith index of the array `y` corresponds to the time at the ith index of array `tspan`.

In code, when `y' = 3y - 6`, the formula becomes

```
y(i+1) = y(i-1) + 2*h*(3*y(i) - 6);
```

Notice that the derivative term uses `y(i)` not `y(i-1)` because it's the derivative at the *current* timestep `t(i)`.

With the correctly implemented central difference formula, the coefficient of `h` should be 2.

Comment: On re-reading, it makes sense. I was reading it as "the value of h", but that's not what you write. :)